# How do i call Marklogic REST API Extension from the NodeJs application

Tags: marklogic

How do  call Marklogic REST API Extension from the NodeJs Application?

As right now I am creating the nodejs application and wanted to use the rest api extension which I have already created earlier.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your code and explain what is not working. See best practice for asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to doing something like:

```
db.extension.get('my-rest-extension')
```

I recommend reading up on 'Working with Resource Service Extensions' in the node-dev guide:

```
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/extensions#id_44792
```

HTH!